# Time Complexity for Generic Functions

Tags: c++, generics, time-complexity

When determining the time complexity of a generic algorithm, should one factor in the effect of the size of the generic type on the algorithm?

For example, given a generic function that merely copies an object/structure byte-by-byte from one memory location to another, such as the following:

```cpp
template<typename Type>
void copy(Type & destination, const Type & source)
{
    char * destination_pointer { reinterpret_cast<char *>(&destination) };
    const char * source_pointer { reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&source) };

    for(std::size_t index { 0 }; index < sizeof(Type); ++index)
        destination_pointer[index] = source_pointer[index];
}
```

One the one hand one could interpret that as being linear time (`O(n)` where `n` is the size of the generic type (`Type`)), because if the type is larger then more bytes will need to be copied and thus the function will take longer.

But on the other hand, when one considers a type individually, the function will take the same time for every value of that type, which sounds more like constant time (`O(1)`).

*Which of those two interpretations is the 'correct' one?*

Comment: Please add the tag for the language

Comment: @Bohemian Does the language matter? This seems to me to be a mostly language-agnostic question. Granted, some languages (e.g. Java) have types that are only references, but in that case my byte-by-byte copy example wouldn't apply anyway.

Comment: I think language is relevant. There are probably some nuances with your example code that require a language-expert eye to assess.

Comment: Complexity is defined in terms of primitive operations. You can define a primitive operations however you like. The complexity will change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Which of those two interpretations is the 'correct' one?

**O(n)**

Why : because you're evaluating the complexity of an *algorithm* over a *problem of size n* : what ever the type or the cost of the copy, your algorithm at that function level is always the same : a loop over a problem of size n.

The fact that you're code abstracts away the implementation of the type, further helps to generalize your algorithm and its complexity. What's important here is that, in your code, you imply that **your type has a size** and that this size correspond to a linear problem size, that is : you imply that your `Type` is a **sequence** of size `sizeof(Type)` and that you can loop over its elements in a linear fashion (that is: from 0 to n-1).

Note that a O(n) complexity doesn't tell you the real time you're algorithm will take to process your data of size n. If each each copy takes 1 day, and you have a
"Type" of size 7, your algorithm will take a week to complete and still be O(n).
Compare that type to an instance of a `Type`, of size 1000000 but where it takes 10ns to do a copy for example.

Also note, that there exist algorithms that have their complexity dependant on the data of the problem. They are called pseudo-polynomial algorithms. You're generic function here **is not a pseudo-polynomial algorithm in itself**. You have to analyze the implementation of all `Type` methods to know if your algorithm is pseudo-polynomial, for example :

- the implementation of the `=` operator could be data dependant,
- the implementation of the `sizeof` method could be data dependant.
- the implementation of [index] could be data dependant.

A last point:

> the function will take the same time for every value of that type,
> which sounds more like constant time (O(1)).

In this sentence, don't forget that even if it's the same time to access or copy elements of the `Type`, you're always doing it n times.